# How to check if an element with .Attr has a particular class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the HTML structure:

```
<div data-step="1"></div>
<div data-step"2" class="active"></div>
```

Something along those lines (the following is obviously wrong, it's just to provide an idea)

```
if($("div").attr("data-step", "2").hasClass("active")) {
  //do this...
}
```

Comment: The `$("div").attr("data-step", "2")` sets a value

Comment: @LGSon I am aware that is wrong, was just a more verbal example to try to better explain what I am looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to get the element with a certain attribute value.  With [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method it simply sets the attribute value and returns the jQuery element object.

```
if($("div[data-step='2']").hasClass("active"))

// or simply combine the class with selector and
// check existance simply by checking its length
if($("div[data-step='2'].active").length)
```

Comment: @rob.m : glad to help :)